# "_dateparsefailure" while parsing date using date in logstash

Tags: logstash, elk, logstash-filter

my date which is in below format

```
"_messagetime" => "08/08/2022 22:18:17.254 +0530"
```

I am using date filter in my logstash

```
date {
    match => ["_messagetime", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
}
```

but I am getting

```
"_dateparsefailure"
```

Can anyone plz suggest what might be wrong with my approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date filter must match the entire value of the field. It cannot just parse a prefix. Also, your date filter has YYYY-MM-dd, but your field has dd/MM/YYYY.

You can parse that field using

```
date { match => ["_messagetime", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS Z"] }
```

to get `"@timestamp" => 2022-08-08T16:48:17.254Z`. Note the trailing Z in the value of [@timestamp] -- all timestamps in logstash are stored in Zulu / UTC timezone.

Comment: Works fine after adding Z, which was missing here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your error it's caused by the " +0530" string in the *_messagetime* field content.

To fix this, one option is :

- Remove this string before the date plugin, you can do this with use of [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) or [dissect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html)

For example :

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "_messagetime" => "%{DATESTAMP:newdate}%{DATA:trash}" }
  }
}
```

- Apply the same date plugin conf wich must work on new content now without " +0530" occurence